# How to track previous row status count

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate count of order status changes within different states. 
My Orderstatus table:

```
| id |ordr_id|   status   |
|----|-------|------------|
| 1  |   1   | pending    |
| 2  |   1   | processing |
| 3  |   1   | complete   |
| 4  |   2   | pending    |
| 5  |   2   | cancelled  |
| 6  |   3   | processing |
| 7  |   3   | complete   |
| 8  |   4   | pending    |
| 9  |   4   | processing |
```

Output I want:

```
|        state         | count |
|----------------------|-------|
| pending->processing  |   2   |
| processing->complete |   2   |
| pending->cancelled   |   1   |
```

Currently I'm fetching the results by `SELECT order_id,GROUP_CONCAT(status) as track FROM table group by order_id` and then process the data in php to get the output. But is that possible in query itself ?

Comment: Your id column has 8 twice. Is that by mistake? If its a mistake, is value in that id column make sure the real order of data?

Comment: it was a typo.. thanks corrected

Answer (score 2):

Use `lag()`:

```
select prev_status, status, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by order_id order by status) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
group by prev_status, status;
```

`LAG()` is available in MySQL starting with version 8.

Note that you can filter out the first status for each order by putting `where prev_status is not null` in the outer query.

Your version is not quite correct, because it does not enforce the ordering.  It should be:

```
SELECT order_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(status ORDER BY id) as track
```

EDIT:

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select prev_status, status, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.status
              from t t2
              where t2.order_id = t.order_id and t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
group by prev_status, status;
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is alternative to `lag` for < mysql8. I'm using mysql5.7.

Comment: You need `limit 1` in your second query.

Answer (score 1):

If id column ensure the sequence of records, you can use self join to achieve your requirement as below-

```
SELECT A.Status +'>'+ B.Status, COUNT(*) 
FROM OrderStatus A
INNER JOIN OrderStatus B
ON A.id = B.id -1
WHERE B.Status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.Status +'>'+ B.Status
```

Answer (score 1):

With a join of the 3 status change types to the grouping of the table that you already did:

```
select c.changetype, count(*) counter
from (
  select 'pending->processing' changetype union all
  select 'processing->complete' union all
  select 'pending->cancelled'
) c inner join ( 
  select 
    group_concat(status order by id separator '->') changestatus
  from tablename  
  group by ordr_id  
) t on concat('->', t.changestatus, '->') like concat('%->', changetype, '->%')
group by c.changetype
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=baf4cb5b3b5a1a98a8ab61ae9a9ba796).
Results:

```
> changetype           | counter
> :------------------- | ------:
> pending->cancelled   |       1
> pending->processing  |       2
> processing->complete |       2
```

Answer (score 1):

...or just a simple join...

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.status,'->',b.status) action
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.ordr_id = a.ordr_id 
   AND b.id = a.id + 1
 GROUP 
    BY action;
+----------------------+-------+
| action               | total |
+----------------------+-------+
| pending->cancelled   |     1 |
| pending->processing  |     2 |
| processing->complete |     2 |
+----------------------+-------+
```

Note that this relies on the fact that ids are contiguous.